# Is Flynn adjustment for IQ scores viable?

Tags: intelligence, iq

I was IQ tested with a test battery that was normed 27 years ago when i was 8 (WISC-R)(It was normed 27 years ago when I was 8). My Verbal IQ score was 122 and my Performance IQ score was 130. I found a paper about my contry's Flynn Effect IQ gains. It stated that for WISC-R and WISC-IV, we can expect a score discrepancy of roughly 7 points between Verbal IQ score and VCI score. Similarly, we can expect a discrepancy of roughly 15 points between Performance IQ score and PRI score (WISC-IV is very recently normed in my country.) Given these numbers, this question came to my mind: Can somebody Flynn adjust his/her inflated IQ score and get a reasonably accurate IQ score estimation?

Comment: I'm not clear on the question.  Are you asking if someone who took the test this year can roughly predict what their score would have been if they travel back in time 27 years and take the test again?  I think that's the point of the adjustment, yes.

Comment: No, I am asking that if somebody were to take a test that was normed, say, 30 years ago, would they able to substract 10 points and say that's a sorta reliable iq score?